# How to get only time from date-time C#

Tags: c#, datetime, time

Suppose I have the value 6/22/2009 10:00:00 AM. How do I get only 10:00 Am from this date time.

Comment: Is this a string or a DateTime?

Comment: string Time = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss:tt");

Comment: string t1 = dt.ToString("H:mm");

Answer (score 252):

You have many options for this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("6/22/2009 07:00:00 AM");

dt.ToString("HH:mm"); // 07:00 // 24 hour clock // hour is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("hh:mm tt"); // 07:00 AM // 12 hour clock // hour is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("H:mm"); // 7:00 // 24 hour clock
dt.ToString("h:mm tt"); // 7:00 AM // 12 hour clock
```

Helpful Link:
[DateTime.ToString() Patterns](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm)

Comment: @MetroSmurf - the OP is, of course, not clear what he wants to do. One of my pet hates is to go to strings to early. I had a colleague who converted everything to string - even doubles etc. It's an accident waiting to happen. I would say don't convert objects to strings until you want to display the object to a human. Until then stick with the objects.

Comment: For quick reference, `ss` is seconds with a leading zero and `s` is seconds without

Comment: best answer so far

Answer (score 91):

From a `DateTime`, you can use `.TimeOfDay` - but that gives you a `TimeSpan` representing the time into the day (10 hours).

Comment: or special cases with Formatting on ToString("format codes")

Answer (score 83):

There is only DateTime type in C# and it consist of both the date and time portion. If you don't care about the Date portion of DateTime, set it to default value like this:

```
DateTime myTime = default(DateTime).Add(myDateTime.TimeOfDay)
```

This way you can be consistent across all versions of .NET, even if Microsoft decides to change the base date to something else than 1/1/0001.

Comment: Specifically, it's "in .NET" not "in C#".

Comment: I used `DateTime.Now.Date.Add(myDateTime.TimeOfDay)` to get the specified time *today*.

Answer (score 23):

You might want to look into the [DateTime.ToShortTimeString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx) method.

Also, there many other methods and properties on the [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_members.aspx) object that can help you in formating the date or time in any way you like.  Just take a look at the documentation.

Comment: +1 This is the cleanest solution, if you are running in an international environment with requirement of localization of the time output, since it returns the time in whatever format  the current system has been set to.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
TimeSpan TodayTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 14):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

now.ToLongDateString();    // Wednesday, January 2, 2019
now.ToLongTimeString();    // 2:33:59 PM
now.ToShortDateString();   // 1/2/2019
now.ToShortTimeString();   // 2:16 PM
now.ToString();            // 1/2/2019 2:33:59 PM
```

Answer (score 8):

There are different ways to do so. You can use `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()` which
returns only the time in string format.

Comment: You probably meant `DateTime.ToLongTimeString()` rather than `DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()`. Given the age of this thread, best not to resurrect it unless the response contributes a significant improvement over previous answers.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply write

```
string time = dateTimeObect.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: this adds absolutely nothing to what has already been submitted over 4 years ago!

Answer (score 6):

You can use this

```
lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
```

It is realtime with milliseconds value and it sets to time only.

Comment: TimeOfDay is a good way but it brings miliseconds part too you need to format your time with standard type.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me. I discovered it when I had to work with DateTime.Date to get only the date part.

```
var wholeDate = DateTime.Parse("6/22/2009 10:00:00 AM");
var time = wholeDate - wholeDate.Date;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ToString("T")` for long time or `ToString("t")` for short time.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to compare times, and not the dates, you could just have a standard comparison date, or match to the date you're using, as in...

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Parse("6/22/2009 10:00AM");
DateTime compare = DateTime.Parse(time.ToShortDateString() + " 2:00PM");
bool greater = (time > compare);
```

There may be better ways to to this, but keeps your dates matching.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using gridview then you can show only the time with `DataFormatString="{0:t}"`
example:

```
    By bind the value:-
<asp:Label ID="lblreg" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Registration_Time ", "{0:t}") %>'></asp:Label>

By bound filed:-
<asp:BoundField DataField=" Registration_Time" HeaderText="Brithday" SortExpression=" Registration Time " DataFormatString="{0:t}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to account for DateTime Kind too.

```
public static DateTime GetTime(this DateTime d)
{
    return new DateTime(d.TimeOfDay.Ticks, d.Kind);
}
```

Comment: No point for answering this question, it was asked 9 year ago. Also there are many good answers to this question already.

Comment: You are not returning the time.  You should review your answer

Comment: @Yepeekai  There is no Time class in .NET. So a DateTime instance with no Date portion is one of the options you can do. You can also return a string but you can use that in DateTime operations. I guess you could consider a TimeSpan too.

Comment: imo the "new DateTime(d.TimeOfDay.Ticks)" is the cleanest answer so far