# Convert AM/PM time to 24 hours format?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert 12 hours format time (am/pm) to 24 hours format time, e.g. 01:00 PM to 13:00 using C#. How can I convert it?

Comment: what is the format of the source data?

Comment: What is the type of the format? Do you want toi cas a string or a DateTime?

Comment: @phoog format is h:mm tt

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have such thing like format. Its applied only when you're using `ToString`, so are your variables of type `string` ?

Comment: @nmathur is it a string or a DateTime value?

Comment: `HH` should get you the 24 hr format, but what is getting converted to what is the question

Comment: @Piotr Auguscik  when i use ToString() it returns 1:00:00 PM but i need 13:00:00

Comment: @nmathur check what bobbymcr has suggested it should work for you

Comment: @nmathur Check bobbymcr's answer, its all what you need. Your server must have defined enviroment variables telling him to convert `DateTime` to 12 hours format. So you have to change server setting or force the format you prefer everywhere where `tostring` is called

Comment: @phoog it is a String and when i convert it into DateTime AM or PM remains in Date.

Comment: @Abdul i tried to Convert it to DateTime

Comment: @V4Vendetta thanks pal, HH worked .. :) and thank you all for you suggestions.

Comment: @nmathur It seems hard for you to tell what is the `Type` where the date and time are stored... Do you need to convert a `string` *"4 PM"* into another `string` "*16:00*" or do you want to print a `DateTime` in the format you want?

Comment: Try putting more effort into formulating your question. Use formatting, give examples, etc.

Answer (score 40):

If you need to convert a string to a DateTime you could try

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("01:00 PM"); // No error checking
```

or (with error checking)

```
DateTime dt;
bool res = DateTime.TryParse("01:00 PM", out dt);
```

Variable `dt` contains your datetime, so you can write it

```
dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Last one works for every DateTime var you have, so if you still have a DateTime, you can write it out in this way.

Comment: for the last one:
No overload method ToString takes one argument

Answer (score 19):

You'll want to become familiar with [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

```
DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;

// 24 hour format -- use 'H' or 'HH'
string timeString24Hour = localTime.ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 15):

Convert a string to a DateTime, you could try

```
    DateTime timeValue = Convert.ToDateTime("01:00 PM");
    Console.WriteLine(timeValue.ToString("HH:mm"));
```

Comment: This answer can also convert Nullable<DateTime> format.. nice..

Answer (score 6):

```
int hour = your hour value;
int min = your minute value;
String ampm = your am/pm value;

hour = ampm == "AM" ? hour : (hour % 12) + 12; //convert 12-hour time to 24-hour

var dateTime = new DateTime(0,0,0, hour, min, 0);
var timeString = dateTime.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: for AM, should be `(hour % 12)`

Answer (score 6):

Go through following code to convert the DateTime from 12 hrs to 24 hours.

```
string currentDateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm tt");
DateTime currentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(currentDateString);
Console.WriteLine("String Current Date: " + currentDateString);
Console.WriteLine("Converted Date: " + currentDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm"));
```

Whenever you want the time should be displayed in24 hours use format "HH"

You can refer following link for further details:
[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You can use like this:

```
string date = "";

date = DateTime.ParseExact("01:00 PM" , "h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("HH:mm");
```

> h: 12 hours
>
> mm: mins
>
> tt: PM/AM
>
> HH:24 hours

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

class Solution
{
    static string timeConversion(string s)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(s).ToString("HH:mm");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(timeConversion("01:00 PM"));
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here what I find:

```
string timeIn12Hour = "07:35:50PM";
DateTime parsedTime = DateTime.ParseExact(timeIn12Hour, "hh:mm:sstt", null);
string timeIn24Hours = parsedTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");   // 19:35:50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method to obtain a DateTime object. You can then use the ToString() method of that DateTime object to convert the string to what ever you need as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026841/how-to-get-only-time-from-date-time).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static string ConvertFrom12To24HoursFormat(string inputTime)
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(inputTime).ToString("hh:mm");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ConvertFrom12To24HoursFormat("01:05 pm"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use Cultures to parse and format your string, eg

```
var cultureSource = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
var cultureDest = new CultureInfo("de-DE", false);

var source = "01:00 pm";

var dt = DateTime.Parse(source, cultureSource);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("t", cultureDest));
```

This prints `13:00`