# Binding time values to asp.net GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to bind time values to my gridview. For example, if the time is 13:00, I need to display it as 13-00 in the grid. But it displays as 01-00. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value into 24-hour format (for instance by selecting a different culture for your application) or simply create some converter class that will convert this for you. There are multiple resources to learn from.

Something like this should work:

```
DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;
// 24 hour format -- use 'H' or 'HH'
string timeString24Hour = localTime.ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Taken from another answer here in SO [Convert AM/PM time to 24 hours format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337625/convert-am-pm-time-to-24-hours-format)

If your culture uses 12-hour format, use a different culture info for the parsing that supports 24-hour format.

Of course you'd probably like to wrap this in a getter property so it will be available for the binding

```
public string DateIn24HourFormat
{
    get
    {
        return MyConvertFunction(this.Time);
    }
}
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Say, I choose a value from the dropdown which I have in a popup window. When I click add button, I need to populate that value to the grid's row. How do I do that?

Comment: @Aishvarya, that's a completely separate question! :) You need to create an event handler for the click event and in this you'd have to set the `DataSource` of your GridView and called the method `.DataBind()` on it. DataSource should take the data from some external method returning a collection inheriting from IEnumerable containing items that have this getter property I've shown you. In your GridView simply reference the `DateIn24HourFormat` property and it should give you correct output. If you want to continue a debate about databinding, create probably a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) Event to achieve it. Format your time string as you want and assign to to the grid view cell.

You can use date formats to convert datetime into 24-hrs format.

```
 void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      e.Row.Cells[1].Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
    }
  }
```

Comment: My question is how to format the time to display it as I asked.

Comment: That is I am doing in `Row_DataBound` event. You can format the Time String using datetime format as I have written in my example.

Comment: Say, I choose a value from the dropdown which I have in a popup window. When I click add button, I need to populate that value to the grid's row. How do I do that?

Comment: Add that value in your GridView DataSource and then rebind the gridview

Answer (score 0):

Give your Time format in `DataFormatString` property in `BoundColumn`.
Apply format as

```
{0:HH-mm}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx

Comment: Say, I choose a value from the dropdown which I have in a popup window. When I click add button, I need to populate that value to the grid's row. How do I do that?