# Converting a Time String to 24hr Time as Time Only

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I convert a string representing 12-hour time into a time-only, 24hr format? Here's my code so far.

```
string[] ar;
string s = "7:00 AM - 9:00 AM";
ar = s.Split('-');
s = String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", ar[0]);
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337625/convert-am-pm-time-to-24-hours-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] ar;
string s = "7:00 AM - 9:00 AM";
ar = s.Split('-');
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(ar[0]);
dateTime.ToString("HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  string s = "7:00 PM";
  DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(s);
  Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("HH:mm"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
string[] ar;
        string s = "7:00 AM - 9:00 AM";
        ar = s.Split('-');
        s = Convert.ToDatetime(ar[0]).ToString("HH:mm");
```