# converting Chinese datetime string throws error

Tags: c#, datetime

Used a dateTimePicker control to get the DateTime in the following format.

```
 string val = "20-12月-2020 下午 8:06:19 +0800";
```

When tried to convert it back to Datetime value using

```
Convert.ToDateTime(val)
```

it throws an error ***"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."***

How can we convert the string back to datetime object.

Comment: Use this [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime?view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ToDateTime_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) and specify the correct culture

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work.

Comment: For those of us that don't read Chinese  - are those Chinese chars significant to the date value, or can you ignore them? Are they always the same chars?

Comment: A similar question has been answered there:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813210/780815