# C# Date time object with 24 hour format Without Am PM

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I am trying to set the `DateTime` format to 24 hours. Originally I have a string with a 12 hour representation. All solutions I have found are converting `DateTime` to string.

```
string dateString = "Mon 16 Jun 8:30 AM 2008"; // <-- Valid
        string format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
        DateTime dateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out dateTime))
        {
            DateTime dateIn24 = dateTime;//  dateIn24 should be in 24 hour format
        }
```

Is there anything we can do in `web.config`? Like the following:

```
    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

i got the answer

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
if its en-US 12 hour format 
by default it will be en-US based on system date time settings

Comment: Take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337625/convert-am-pm-time-to-24-hours-format

Comment: i have gone through it ..they are converting date to string ..i need to output as date time object

Comment: DateTime has no format unless you are printing it as a string. Otherwise it has its internal representation which is the same "format" for all instances

Comment: @Lijo If you found a solution, you should answer your question yourself and mark your answer as the solution :/

Comment: Still the solution you've found is misleading. There **is no** internal 12 hours or 24 hours representation. The default `ToString` implementation uses the current culture to format the `DateTime`. Hence you will get a 12 hour representation, when the `CurrentCulture` is en-US. This is - more or less - what I've written in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The **DateTime** instance only contains the information, and the **Hour** property is an integer from 0 to 23, according to MSDN documentation:

> **Property Value**
>
> **Type**: System.Int32
>
> The hour component, expressed as a value between 0 and 23.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.hour(v=vs.110).aspx

If you're talking about **formatting** it, then you need to convert it to a string, like mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the 24-hour format is neither not a matter of how the `DateTime` is parsed, nor saved, but rather of the formatting. Given that you enter the `if`-block (I have not been successful on parsing youre `dateString` in LinqPad) you can obtain a correctly formatted date string with

```
var dateStringWith24Hours = dateTime.ToString(dateString);
```

since the `HH` in your format string means that you'd like to format the hours as 24 hours.

Comment: This is what I am talking about. Internally the `DateTime` will always have a 24 hour representation. The 12-hour format is only relevant when converting the `DateTime` to a string. Maybe you could elaborate *why* and *how* you need the 12-hour format and then we could propose a solution.

Comment: by default date time is having 12 hour format  . i need in 24 hour format

Comment: To repeat myself: The `DateTime` structure does not know anything about a 12 hour representation. Only the respective formatting methods do.

Comment: create simple windows form application check datetime.now formt

Comment: "create simple windows form application check datetime.now formt" - when you do that, VS converts DateTime.Now to a string, and you see a representation of it in the IDE. Internally, it's only a set of variables containing the hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

Comment: Yeah, for me this will result in a 24 h representation (believe me), but this is only due to the implementation of `ToString`, not due to some internal representation. To display a `DateTime` as a string it has to be converted to - well - a `string`. This is done via `ToString`, which uses your current culture.

Comment: @EmersonCardoso Thanks for your effort, but I do not think that he'll believe us...

Comment: so you mean to say date time will always show 24 hour.please assign the date time to a date time variable and check....plz..

Comment: date we can format to string as we wish..but am talking about the date time culture  ...even we can set the culture in iis globalization.

Comment: Yes, the **textual** representation depends on the culture, I didn't state anything else. But the **internal** (numeric) representation is completely independent from the culture.