# Convert AM/PM time to 24 hours format in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, time

I am trying to solve the [Time Conversion problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/time-conversion/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) of HackerRank in C#. Basically, you are given a string in AM/PM format and you need to convert it to military time (24 hours time format).

The sample input is: 07:05:45PM
Expected output is: 19:05:45

I have tried "DateTime.Parse(timeString)", the solution proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8337625/convert-am-pm-time-to-24-hours-format), but it gives me wrong answer (I get 07:05:45 as output, it only removes the AM/PM):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("01:00 PM");
dt.ToString("HH:mm");
```

I searched a little more in [DateTime library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0#parsing-02) and also tried [DateTime.TryParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0), but I get the same result:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

class Solution {
    
    static string timeConversion(string inputTimeString) 
    {    
        DateTime outputTime;
        
        bool res = DateTime.TryParseExact(
            inputTimeString, 
            "hh:mm:sstt", 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None, 
            out outputTime);
        
        //Console.WriteLine("res: " + res);
        
        return outputTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        string result = timeConversion(s);

        tw.WriteLine(result);

        tw.Flush();
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is `outputTime.ToString("hh:mm:ss")`, not `outputTime.ToString("HH:mm")` (as you stated above).

Comment: Thanks, John. You are correct. That was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```
"hh"    The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.

"HH"    The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
```

So use HH.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much.