# c# show only Time portion of DateTime

Tags: c#

I have a date that shows up as 10/18/2011 3:12:33 PM

How do I get only the time portion of this datetime?

I am using C#.

I tried:

```
      string timeval = PgTime.ToShortTimeString();
```

but that did not work as Intellisense only showed ToString();

Comment: You haven't given us enough context. What's the compile-time type of `PgTime`? What compiler error did you get with that code? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Answered here:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026841/how-to-get-only-time-from-date-time][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026841/how-to-get-only-time-from-date-time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that

```
DateTime PgTime;
```

You can:

```
String timeOnly = PgTime.ToString("t");
```

Other format options [can be viewed on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx).

Also, if you'd like to combine it in a larger string, you can do either:

```
// Instruct String.Format to parse it as time format using `{0:t}`
String.Format("The time is: {0:t}", PgTime);

// pass it an already-formatted string
String.Format("The time is: {0}", PgTime.ToString("t"));
```

If `PgTime` is a `TimeSpan`, you have [a few other options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx):

```
TimeSpan PgTime;

String formattedTime = PgTime.ToString("c"); // 00:00:00 [TimeSpan.ToString()]
String formattedTime = PgTime.ToString("g"); // 0:00:00
String formattedTime = PgTime.ToString("G"); // 0:00:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want a formatted string, just use `.ToString(format)`, specifying only time portions. If you want the actual time, use `.TimeOfDay`, which will be a `TimeSpan` from midnight.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime PgTime = new DateTime();
        var hr = PgTime.Hour;
        var min = PgTime.Minute;
        var sec = PgTime.Second;

        //or

        DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") gives it to you as a string.
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't now nothing about a class named `PgTime`. Do now about `DateTime`, though.

Try

```
DateTime instance = DateTime.Now           ; // current date/time
string   time     = instance.ToString("t") ; // short time formatted according to the rules for the current culture/locale
```

Might want to read up on [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In [C# 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10?ranMID=46131&ranEAID=a1LgFw09t88&ranSiteID=a1LgFw09t88-NhYtU9N1CtcRDImZdW4tZw&epi=a1LgFw09t88-NhYtU9N1CtcRDImZdW4tZw&irgwc=1&OCID=AID2200057_aff_7806_1243925&tduid=%28ir__cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xozb2s63cobiu00%29%287806%29%281243925%29%28a1LgFw09t88-NhYtU9N1CtcRDImZdW4tZw%29%28%29&irclickid=_cl20z3o2j9kfq3zbkk0sohz31m2xozb2s63cobiu00) you can use [TimeOnly](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/using-dateonly-and-timeonly-in-dotnet-6).

```
TimeOnly date = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(PgTime);
```