# Table aggregation using linq (calculate Average value)

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities, aggregate, aggregation

How to Aggregate below table using linq query

```
Date                tagname                                 value
06-06-2018 14:15:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   54.73497
06-06-2018 14:15:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(5)   3.417564
06-06-2018 14:15:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   94.82829
06-06-2018 14:15:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   15.08091
06-06-2018 14:15:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(5)   3.6422
06-06-2018 14:15:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   5.078211
06-06-2018 14:15:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   68.00956
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(5)   94.6864
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   32.43211
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   65.16206
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(5)   81.18947
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   4.419947
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   95.77668
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(5)   10.43907
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   79.12902
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   62.20364
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(5)   97.43433
06-06-2018 14:30:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   25.74978
06-06-2018 14:45:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(5)   50.49747
06-06-2018 14:45:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   65.33123
06-06-2018 14:45:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   18.90912
06-06-2018 14:45:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(5)   55.9916
06-06-2018 14:45:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   23.86106
06-06-2018 14:45:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)   18.72116
06-06-2018 14:45:00 Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(5)   0.06596069
```

expected result should be like

only distinct tagname per timeslot with avegate value into that slot,

e.g.
output should be

```
06-06-2018 14:15:00  Poll.Register Block 0.310-PT-304(4) "Value should be avg"
06-06-2018 14:15:00  Poll.Register Block 0.310-PT-304(5) "Value should be avg"
06-06-2018 14:30:00  Poll.Register Block 0.310-PT-304(4) "Value should be avg"
06-06-2018 14:30:00  Poll.Register Block 0.310-PT-304(5) "Value should be avg"
06-06-2018 14:45:00  Poll.Register Block 0.310-PT-304(4) "Value should be avg"
06-06-2018 14:45:00  Poll.Register Block 0.310-PT-304(5) "Value should be avg"
```

--- EDIT -- 
These are couple of queries I've tried..

```
var g = (from x in ObjEntities.TagDataValues
                             where x.ValueDateTime >= FromDate && x.ValueDateTime <= EndDate && MachineName.Contains(x.MachineName) && ServerName.Contains(x.ServerName) && Tags.Contains(x.TagName)

                             select new
                             {
                                 TagName = x.TagName,
                                 MachineName = x.MachineName,
                                 ServerName = x.ServerName,
                                 TagValue = x.TagValue,
                                 DtTime = x.ValueDateTime
                             }).ToList().GroupBy(cd => new
                             {
                                 date = cd.DtTime.AddSeconds(-cd.DtTime.Second).AddMinutes(-cd.DtTime.Minute % 15),
                                 tagname = cd.TagName,
                                 tagvalue = cd.TagValue
                             }).ToList().Select(o => new
                             {
                                 Date = o.Key.date,
                                 tagname = o.Key.tagname,
                                 value = o.Key.tagvalue
                             }).ToList().GroupBy(tr => tr.tagname).Select(x => new {
                                TagName = x.Key,
                                Value = x.Average(gf => gf.value),
                                Date = x.Select(gf => gf.Date).Distinct()
                             }).ToList();





var g = (from x in ObjEntities.TagDataValues
                             where x.ValueDateTime >= FromDate && x.ValueDateTime <= EndDate && MachineName.Contains(x.MachineName) && ServerName.Contains(x.ServerName) && Tags.Contains(x.TagName)

                             select new
                             {
                                 TagName = x.TagName,
                                 MachineName = x.MachineName,
                                 ServerName = x.ServerName,
                                 TagValue = x.TagValue,
                                 DtTime = x.ValueDateTime
                             }).ToList().GroupBy(cd => new
                             {
                                 date = cd.DtTime.AddSeconds(-cd.DtTime.Second).AddMinutes(-cd.DtTime.Minute % 15),
                                 tagname = cd.TagName,
                                 tagvalue = cd.TagValue
                             }).ToList().Select(o => new
                             {
                                 Date = o.Key.date,
                                 tagname = o.Key.tagname,
                                 value = o.Key.tagvalue
                             }).ToList().GroupBy(tr => new {
                                TagName = tr.tagname,
                                DateTime = tr.Date
                             } ).Select(x => new {
                                TagName = x.Key,
                                Value = x.Average(gf => gf.value),
                                Date = x.Key.DateTime
                             }).ToList();
```

I'm new to LINQ, so not able to pull proper result..

I've written sql query for same, its give perfect result as of

```
declare @StartDate DateTime = CAST('06/06/2018 14:26:56' AS datetime) declare @EndDate DateTime = CAST('06/06/2018 14:32:56' AS datetime) SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, ValueDateTime, 113) as MINUTE , avg(TagDataValue.TagValue) Value, TagName FROM TagDataValue WHERE ValueDateTime >=  @StartDate AND ValueDateTime <= @EndDate and TagName in ('Poll.Registers Block 0.310-PT-304_(4)','Poll.Registers Block
0.310-PT-304_(5)') GROUP BY CONVERT(nvarchar, ValueDateTime, 113) , TagName
```

This query gives perfect result but since code is in linq not able to use this query or able to convert the same.

Any help pls..

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @DavidG yes I tried couple of queries with reference of http://blog.pixentia.com/aggregate-data-using-entity-framework also tried to add values into forloop but not able to get values .. :(

Comment: Then show us what you have tried and what is not working with it. This isn't a code writing service I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidG please have look to edit section.. these are some queries what I've tried. but nt able to get result :(

Comment: @DavidG Also tried using Group function with refernce https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/aggregate-functions-in-linq-to-sql/ but its grouped all tags in list and didn't give datetime.. :( kind of stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouping by DateTimes is always tricky as many functions available at C# are not available when generating SQL code and probably can cause problems.

As I have no way to reproduce your environment, I have created some example based only linq.  You probably will have to recreated using TruncateTime so that it runs fully at DB level.

```
var g = entityList
                .Where(x => x.ValueDateTime >= FromDate && x.ValueDateTime <= ToDate && MachineNames.Contains(x.MachineName))
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    quarterDateTime = x.ValueDateTime
                                       .AddSeconds(-x.ValueDateTime.Second)
                                       .AddMinutes(-x.ValueDateTime.Minute % 15),
                    x.MachineName,
                    x.Value
                })
                .GroupBy( x => new { x.quarterDateTime, x.MachineName })
                .Select( x => new {  x.Key.quarterDateTime, x.Key.MachineName, AverageValue = x.Average(p => p.Value) })
                .OrderBy( x => x.quarterDateTime )
                .ToList();
```

I would say, that probably the 1st Select and GroupBy can be merged, but I left separated for better readibility.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912381/how-to-truncate-time-part-from-date-in-linq-query/43912609) for more information about TruncateTime.

Comment: Just updated the answer.  I have coded some sample, using similar classes, etc.. as you but without a DB.  It's working as you were requesting.  Let me know if works and if you need the rest of the code (irrelevant for the answer, but just in case you need it).