# Get Time Value of DateTime string in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I am a beginner at C#. I have a DataGridView which displays:

```
string Column4 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(7).ToString();
```

How do I then retrieve just the time value (i.e 07:00:00) as a string later?

EDIT: The date should be in the format it is currently and remain that way in DataGridView, but for example when I do:

```
 string newString = Column4;
 Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

How do I just pull the time value from Column4 rather than the whole date?

EDIT2: Saw the possible duplicate question and tried:

```
 DateTime newString = DateTime.Parse(Column4);
 newString.ToString("HH:mm");
 Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

But this still produced:

02/05/2018 07:00:00

Comment: You don't need to "retrieve" anything, you set the display format. (e.g. `HH:mm:ss`)

Comment: Where are you retrieving data? Can you please share your code?

Comment: When you say "later" do you mean the value when it was first displayed, or when you retrieve it? Also you don't need `AddDays(0)`..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only time from date-time C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026841/how-to-get-only-time-from-date-time-c-sharp)

Comment: the problem is if you add time, say its 3am, the time is now 10am, how would you expect it to know you had added 7 hours at some point?

Comment: Sorry I have been unclear I will update the question.

Comment: @stuartd AddDays(0) should have been AddDays(1). Edited it.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for the link! I thought this is exactly what I needed but it still shows the full date and time for some reason. I have edited in what I tried.

Comment: What does `Console.WriteLine(newString.ToString("HH:mm"));` output? Why do you think that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need time value, you can use  `TimeSpan` structure. This structure represents a time interval that you can adjust as you please. You can use the structure constructor and its method `ToString()` to store the string representation of that time.

This is the code you can use:

```
string Column4 = (new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0)).ToString();
```

If you need to use later the same `TimeSpan` value, I suggest you to store it in a variable:

```
TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
string Column4 = time.ToString();
```

Remember, if you want to make reference of a date, you can use `DateTime` structure. Else, if you need only the time, you can use `TimeSpan` structure.

To convert a `TimeSpan` structure to a `Datetime` structure you can do this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0)).ToString();
```

**Update:** If you just need the time from a `DateTime` structure variable, you can format it:

```
string newString = DateTime.Parse(Column4).ToString("t");

// Result: 7:00
```

**Or**

```
string newString = DateTime.Parse(Column4).ToString("T");

// Result: 7:00:00
```

You can see more string formats at [this Microsoft MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx).

> **In this Microsoft MSDN [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) is an example about how to instantiate a TimeSpan structure with desired time:**
>
> By calling one of its explicit constructors. The following example initializes a TimeSpan value to a specified number of hours, minutes, and seconds:
>
> ```
> TimeSpan interval =  newTimeSpan(2, 14, 18);
> Console.WriteLine(interval.ToString()); // Displays "02:14:18".
> ```

Comment: Sorry I do actually need the date value to be displayed in my DataGridView.

Comment: Ok! I have updated my answer to solve your question!