# Insert time without the date into my database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I tried to insert into my MS Access database a specific format to see how just the "time" in my database behaves, but when I tried to show what I got the date also, but I want to insert just the time.

I tried to convert the `datetime` variable to specific format and insert that

```
DateTime starttime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
DateTime nstarttime = Convert.ToDateTime(starttime.ToString("HH:mm"));
```

`06/04/2019 22:55:00` that what I got and I want just the time 
without the date

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is, that in **.Net** the time part of a DateTime is not a *DateTime* but a *TimeSpan*:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2019, 6, 4, 22, 55, 0);
TimeSpan timePart = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
```

In Access (VBA) however, a "time only" value is the time of the date of the VBA *Date epoch* which is 1899-12-30. Depending on how you insert the time in an Access table, you may have to apply the time part to the epoch to obtain a value like that Access would use:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2019, 6, 4, 22, 55, 0);
TimeSpan timePart = dateTime.TimeOfDay;    
DateTime vbaEpoch = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);
DateTime vbaTime = vbaEpoch.AddTicks(timePart.Ticks);
```

Of course, when reading back the values, ignore the date part:

```
TimeSpan timeOfDay = vbaTime.TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered so many times, but nevertheless here is the link to one of the discussions [Link 1:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026841/how-to-get-only-time-from-date-time-c-sharp)

Please check also this [Link 2](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm) with may useful patterns

This detail is one of the actual examples provided on Link 1:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("6/22/2009 07:00:00 AM");
dt.ToString("HH:mm"); // 07:00 // 24 hour clock // hour is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("hh:mm tt"); // 07:00 AM // 12 hour clock // hour is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("H:mm"); // 7:00 // 24 hour clock
dt.ToString("h:mm tt"); // 7:00 AM // 12 hour clock
```

Hope this helps!
Cheers and happy coding!