# Best way to change DateTime displayed format in webpage grid from SQL table? C#

Tags: c#, sql

I want to change the DateTime from looking like "2012-05-02 24:12:23.000" to just display the hour and minute like "12:00".

The data is automatically put in the SQL table from a UDP message then the webpage loads the data into a grid.

Comment: which dbms are you using ? is it microsoft sql server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get only time from date-time C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026841/how-to-get-only-time-from-date-time-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes it is microsoft sql server.

Comment: @TimothyG. Yes I believe it does. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in sql server :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),getdate(),108)
```

in postgresql:

```
select to_char(now() , 'hh:mi')
```

Comment: This is not the best way to solve this problem. For instance, what if your program needs to support multiple cultures? Since you have turned a date into a string, you lose the ability to accurately sort on it or to format it for other cultures. The comment by Timothy G is the correct way to solve this problem.